# How to determine amount of gaussian noise in image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have multiple colored images of gauges. I apply adaptive Gaussian thresholding to make the filter the image so that the ticks and needle are more prominent. [image]
For the above thresholding I used `cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 2)`. (21,2) seemed to process images best in general.

However, when the gauge images are too dark adaptThresh(21,2) produces much noise
[image]

Increasing the kernel sizes (adaptiveThreshold parameters) filters the salt and pepper noise and produces an image I want.

I want to be able to determine how much Gaussian (salt and pepper) noise in the image so that if there is too much noise, my algorithm will increase the filter size. What is a good metric to measure the amount of noise in this case?

Comment: IMO, your unfolded image has a too low resolution, making binarization less reliable.

Comment: J. Immerkær, “Fast Noise Variance Estimation”, Computer Vision and Image Understanding 64(2):300-302, 1996.

Comment: adaptive threshold's kernel size is too small, causing this highpass appearance. also, threshold relative to local environment should be set a little away from the average.

Answer (score 1):

Get a clean background image. you can use OpenCV to reduce the low-level image info.

code example

```py
img = cv2.imread("/home/xx/Pictures/test.png",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# filter kernel
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.float32) / 25
dst = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, kernel)
img  = img - dst/20
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img.astype(np.uint8), 255, 
cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 2)
cv2.imshow('1',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A popular way to do this is considering the "derivatives" of the picture, or in other words, how much the picture "varies". A popular way to do that is using the [Total-Variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation). There are many ways to define it in the discrete domain, but in the end they boild down to a (weighted) sum of the absolute differences of neighbouring pixels. This means if you have a small total variation if the image comprises large areas (with "short" boundaries) of uniform brightness, and you'll have a big value for noisy or high frequency images.

So a simple way to measure the noise is just measuring the total variation and if that is above a certain threshold you could try to increase the filter size.